# add boost as static lib to project in cmake

Tags: boost, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I need to link boost library as link library to my project...
Build system is cmake v
I do something so:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON) 

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(
    boost_system
    boost_regex
)
```

Build project was build successfull, but ldd print, that my binaries need libboost_system.so.1.62.0, libboost_regex.so.1.62.0(for example)...

```
libboost_system.so.1.62.0 => not found,
libboost_regex.so.1.62.0 => not found
```

What was wrong? Why this libraries are required if we wnat link statically?(sorry for my english)

Comment: Between `set()` and `include_directories()` it should be `find_package(Boost)`, am I right? `but ldd print, that my binaries need libboost_system.so.1.62.0 ...` - I *guess*, `ldd` prints that corresponded libraries are not found? Please, add **exact error message** to your post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, 
libboost_system.so.1.62.0 => not found
libboost_regex.so.1.62.0 => not found

Answer (score 0):

I just add

```
target_link_libraries(
    libboost_system.a
    libboost_regex.a
)
```

It's was enough